# iOS UIImage stretching: How to fit a larger UIImage in a smaller UIImageView without any quality decrease and without any spaces

Tags: ios, uiimageview, cordova

![enter image description here][1]I am taking a UIImage from UIImagePickerController and showing it in a UIImageView. Actually the UIImagePickerController is in full screen and thus the UIImage is also. But UIImageView is not in full screen because of presence of a header bar.

The Image is getting stretched..

How do I fix this..

Please help me someone..

THANKS IN ADVANCE.....

First image is the image picker screen and second one is where I am displaying the UIImage captured from picker in a UIImageView.

![This is my UIImagePickerController][2]

![This is the image after capturing being shown in a UIImageview. ][3]

NOTE: BOTH THE SCREENS ARE IN LANDSCAPE MODE

Answer (score 7):

Use this for your UIImageView

```
 imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

You won't get any space and with scale preserved. However, some part of the image will be clipped off.

If you use:

```
imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

There will be some empty space, but scale is preserved.

Comment: Ok.. You mean to say whatever be my UIImageview size, imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill will work and it won't stretch??? Thanks a lot..

Comment: +1, Yup, Ranjan, the answer is exactly correct.Use it according to your need.

Comment: @Ranjan: Yes, please try it

Comment: After setting the contentMode to UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill the imageview is filling the whole screen even if I am setting the frame to CGRectMake(0, 40, 480, 200). I uploaded that screenshot again with full screen uiimageview. You can see that the header is hidden by the UIImageView there.. PLS advice me..

Comment: try this: imageView.clipsToBounds = YES;

Comment: @user1256663: I tried clipsToBounds too. What is happening is the UIImageview is loading from point (0,0) instead of (0, 40) and some portion of the image is cut from below.

Comment: could you show me your code of that viewController which loaded and added the imageView?